# Media Route found, but no Media Route button is shown

Tags: android, chromecast

I am working on a Chromecast Android Sender app and I've come to a point where I need to test a different receiver.

I registered the new reciever and got the new ID. I added this to my Android project, commenting out the old Id (in the strings.xml file).

I launched my app in debug mode on a test phone.

I get the following in logcat:

> 02-04 16:27:49.968    1532-1532/com.mydomain.app I/MediaRouter﹕ Found default route: MediaRouter.RouteInfo{ uniqueId=android/.support.v7.media.SystemMediaRouteProvider:DEFAULT_ROUTE, name=System, description=null, enabled=true, connecting=false, playbackType=0, playbackStream=3, volumeHandling=1, volume=14, volumeMax=15, presentationDisplayId=-1, extras=null, providerPackageName=android }

But no cast icon is shown in the actionbar.

Before I made this change, the icon was showing without issue.

Changing the ID back (deleting the new one and uncommening the old ID) makes the icon appear again.

Device is running Android 4.0.4

Answer (score 0):

I've had many problems with removing items in the `strings.xml` file. What I've found works best is to first add the new string(s) into the file, Rebuild, then remove the old string(s) from the file. I think references get 'stuck' somehow and the Rebuild usually takes care of that. Though sometimes I find I have to restart Android Studio as well.

Comment: Did a rebuild, cleaned and even restarted Android Studio. No luck so far.

Comment: Yeah it's very tricky to remove those strings from that file. I often end up just leaving them in there and using a new key to refer to the new value.

Comment: I renamed the string name, replaced it in my code. Still nothing. It seems the app is only doing the one check for media routes (finding the default route which apparently is the phone itself) and then not doing anything... Pretty sure when it was working with the old ID, it would scan every so often?

Comment: So, new string name identifier. Put back the old app ID, cast icon shows up. What the heck?!

Comment: Just to confirm you have done the following: left your old key value as is, added a new key value without commenting anything out (and without copy/pasting from the old one), replaced the reference in your code, then rebuilt the project, correct? If this doesn't work, I'd say there's a good chance that the issue is something else.

Comment: No, I removed the old ID entirely, added the new ID with a new string name. Cleaned, rebuilt, restarted Android Studio. Nothing works to make the new ID work.

Comment: So, I have just tried again today, with the new App ID. And guess what - it still doesn't work. The MediaRouter log message I get is still the same as if I use the old, working ID (when the icon shows and a CC device is listed)

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out, nothing was wrong with my application, or the receiver ID.

Whilst I was able to see devices with the old ID, but not the new one, really confused me.

The Chromecast is whitelisted for development, and the application registered (the only way to get an ID!)

I could find and cast to the Chromecast with the old ID (and other apps) without issue.

For some reason, I decided to reboot the Chromecast (shouldn't need to, it was whitelisted ages ago, and I've not had to do so in the past)

After a reboot, eh voila! My new receiver ID worked, and the cast icon was displayed in my app.

So, definitely something fishy going on here.

Answer (score -2):

That is the default route, which basically means the mobile device itself. None of the cast devices on your network are registered for your app id, so nothing shows up except the default route, hence the cast button is hidden.

Comment: In the cast console, I added the new application. There is no option to tie a device to the application. The older app ID works. My CC Device is whitelisted. So it should show up.

Comment: Just to clarify, alls I have done it changed the app ID to a new, unpublished app (the same as the old app ID). Did you even read the fact that the old ID works fine?

Comment: also, I just changed back to the old ID, and the only logging for MediaRouter I got, was the same as in my question. But, the icon is visible and a CC is listed. So your explanation that the default route is the phone doesn't make sense!

Comment: Seems to me that not only you don't understand the cast discovery, you also refuse to accept the help when one is given. The log that you posted in your original post is mentioning the default route and if that is the only route discovered, then cast icon is not going to show up. Are you questioning my statement that the "default route" is the phone??? It is also totally wrong to expect that the new app id should work since the old app id worked. Regardless, good luck with your issue.

Comment: Why would an old ID work and not a new one?! I am saying it doesn't make sense, becuase when using the old, working ID, the same log message was spat out, despite a route actually being available (other then the phone!)